# Storing Uploaded file in database

Tags: file-upload, webforms

I place a simple fileupload control in my webform application. firstly user have to login and his login username is stored in a session. then user have option to upload his pic. I place an image control.If pic is available it is shown in Image control. My fileupload code is

```
 string sp = fileuploadpanno.FileName;
    string fn = Server.MapPath("~/panno/" + sp);
    fileuploadpanno.PostedFile.SaveAs(fn);
```

My question is how to save this file into database. I am using mysql database.

Comment: You generally shouldn't store file data in a relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially store the image in the database directly by first converting it to a [BLOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object).

A more widely used practice is to store the image in a directory/location such as App_Data or Temp and then store the image name in your mysql database. Then when you want to reference the image in your web application you can just use a normal image tag with the source being the location of the image concatenated to the image name you retreive from your database.

So for example if I have a directory `/App_Data/Images/`

And I store an image name in my database called `my_image.jpg`

After moving the image above to the directory above (save it in this location) I can then reference it by appending the image name to the location `/App_Data/Images/my_image.jpg`

Comment: Thanks gimg1, I forget about that. I stored file name in database column. This is what i was looking for.